# Java newbie: why does it not give me the right result?

Tags: java

```
public class Weight {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weight test1 = new Weight(500.12345);
        double test4kilo = test1.getKilograms();
        double test4kilo3 = test1.getPounds();
        double test4kilo4 = test1.getOunces();
        System.out.println(+test4kilo+", "+test4kilo3+", "+test4kilo4);
    }


    double w;

    public Weight(double p){
        p = w;
    }

    public double getPounds(){
        return w;
    }

    public double getKilograms(){
        return w*0.45359237;
    }

    public double getOunces(){
        return w*(1/16);
    }       
}
```

Whenever I run this code it prints "0.0, 0.0, 0.0" which is not the correct answer for the calculations in the methods. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
public Weight(double p){
    p = w;
}
```

to

```
public CopyOfTest1(double p){
        this.w=p;
    }
```

you need to set the value of `w`

**Output**

```
226.85218097807652, 500.12345, 0.0
```

- Include answer from @Eran as well.

Comment: This output is still incorrect. The last number shouldn't be 0.0.

Comment: @Eran given ref for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is from right to left

```
public Weight(double p) {
    w = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getOunces()` is wrong. When you convert pounds to ounces you should be multiplying by 16, not dividing.

It should be :

```
public double getOunces() {
    return w*16;
}
```

Beside that, fix the typo in your constructor, in order to store the passed weight in your object :

```
public Weight(double p){
    w = p;
}
```

You'll get the correct output :

```
226.85218097807652, 500.12345, 8001.9752
```

Answer (score 0):

`p = w;` in the constructor should be  `w = p;`

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect:

```
public Weight(double p){
    p = w;
}
```

Should be:

```
public Weight(double p){
    w = p; //Chnaged
}
```

You missmatch variable assigment.

Answer (score 0):

In you constructor, you are incorrectly equating. do this instead:

```
public Weight(double p){
    w=p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code in the constructor

use this:

```
 public Weight(double p)
    {
    w = p;
    }
```

you were getting this issue because you were giving the value of p=w
and w's initial value is 0
so you are getting 0 throughout
, 
the value of the right goes into the left variable